# Memory error on catalog url index

Tags: indexing, memory

I have tried this

```
[shell]$ php -d memory_limit=2048M indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 858
[shell]$ php -d memory_limit=4096M indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 858
[shell]$ php -d memory_limit=8192M indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 858
[shell]$ php -d memory_limit=16384M indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 858
[shell]$ php -d memory_limit=32768M indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 858
```

I think the server only has 32gb of memory. But really should take that much... 24k URLS in the table

**EDIT:** I modified the .htaccess and increased my memory and now I get this error

```
[shell]$ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: We opened a ticket with Nexcess, after changing the memory in htaccess (Second part of edit) they were able to index as root without issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states: "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted" which is only 256MB. There may be something else changing the memory settings within the script itself. You should check for any `ini_set` calls within 3rd / custom party modules.